# Code to Download file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to give one option in my website to upload multiple files and then allowing users to download those files.
I have done uploading multiple files part, however I am not much clear how I will do downloading part.
I first thought to add hyperlinks dynamically to a label for each file (as I am not sure how many files user will upload).
But then it opens file in browser and does not give option to save or open file.
Main issue is user can submit any type of file like ms doc or xls or text files etc Hence content type is not fixed.

I am not clear on how exactly I will do it I mean adding link buttons dynamically or adding hyperlinks dynamically. And after that how will I download file? I am not able to do

```
Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(@"~/logo_large.gif"));
```

as content type is not clear.
Please help me regarding code for download all types of files

Comment: You need to save the content type and file length when uploading the file. This will make it a lot easier when downloading..

Comment: possible duplicate of [providing dynamic file download in ASP.NET2.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/468893/providing-dynamic-file-download-in-asp-net2-0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for download the file:

```
    public void DownLoad(string FName)
    {
        string path = FName;
        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(path);
        if (file.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            Response.End();

        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
        }

    }
```

but this is for word doc/docx files. in the line: `Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";` you have to define the type of the file.

for displaying hyperlink dynamically write a loop and go over all the files which were uploaded by the user and writh the following code:

```
     yourdivId += "<a href='" + file.FullName + "' >" + file.Name + "</a></br>";
```

Comment: Exactly this is my problem..Content type is not fixed..And I used hyperlink option but It always opens file in browser

Comment: why can't you use switch clause to define the content type according to the extension of the file? and for the hyperlink can you post your code?

Comment: Thank you so much..this works for me..However I tried this with only single file. What I am doing is adding link buttons dynamically for all uploaded files. And on click event file is downloaded. How will I get to know which file is to be downloaded. I mean How can I pass these arguments to event?

Comment: you can put in the name of the linkbutton or the id the name of the file which the button is for. and on the click event take the name and you have the file name.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help u.()

```
 Response.Clear();
 Response.ContentType = YourFile.ToString();
 Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + YourFileName);
 Response.OutputStream.Write(YourFile, 0, YourFile.Length);
 Response.Flush();
 Response.End();

I have tried this to download img,txtfile,zip file,doc it works fine..
but little problem user will face that in my case when i opened a word(doc) file its ask 
me to openwith..? when i select MsWord it opened it correctly.
```

For showing these file you can make a grid view to show all file with a download link...

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can follow different ways.

1. Guide the user during upload and make him specify the file type before starting upload. So the user has to select the content type from a selection. You need to save the correlation between the file and its content type.
2. Create a map between file extensions and mime-types ([See here for example](http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml)). You need to obtain the file extension and save the correlation between that file and its content type.
3. Try to identify the content type automatically. There is a [Windows
   API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775107.aspx) that let you identify the Mime Type of a file. And [here is some code](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bwaldron/archive/2005/01/04/346547.aspx).

After that, you can use [st mnmn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/615827/st-mnmn) solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
try
        {
            string strURL=txtFileName.Text;
            WebClient req=new WebClient();
            HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
            response.Clear();
            response.ClearContent();
            response.ClearHeaders();
            response.Buffer= true;
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\"" + Server.MapPath(strURL) + "\"");
            byte[] data=req.DownloadData(Server.MapPath(strURL));
            response.BinaryWrite(data);
            response.End();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to set few response headers before server sends the file to client. See [How to Download a file with a hyperlink](http://forums.asp.net/t/1204802.aspx/1)