# Why is the file not downloading?

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, ext.net

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870841/code-to-download-file) link to download file that are in the file system. Except I did it using Ext.net link button, and in the click event of that button I added the same *Download* code.

The design part is:

```
<ext:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" runat="server">
        <DirectEvents>
            <Click OnEvent="lnkDownload_Click">
                <EventMask ShowMask="true" />
            </Click>
        </DirectEvents>
    </ext:LinkButton>
```

And the codebehind is:

```
protected void lnkDownload_Click(object s, DirectEventArgs e)
    { 
        string filePath = // Path to the file
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);

        if (file.Exists)
        {
            Response.Clear();
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            if (file.Extension == ".txt")
                Response.ContentType = "application/txt";
            else if (file.Extension == ".jpg")
                Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
            else
                Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
            Context.Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("This file does not exist.");
        }
    }
```

When running the code, error occurs. Text content is displayed for text file, and maybe the encrypted image content is displayed for image file. What is happening? Why is the file not downloading? Please help me how to solve.

The snapshots are:

[image][image]

Comment: Where's the rest of your code for sending the downlaod? What are the screenshots of? An application you've written?

Comment: Oh sorry for that I am updating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For it to work change the code to the following:

```
<ext:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" runat="server">
        <DirectEvents>
            <Click OnEvent="lnkDownload_Click" IsUpload="true">
                <EventMask ShowMask="true" />
            </Click>
        </DirectEvents>
</ext:LinkButton>
```

**Note**: I think the content type should always be "application/octet-stream".

**Edit**

For the Mask, as per [Daniil from the Ext.NET Team](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?27575-Download-File-using-DirectEvent), [its not possible without a workaround](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?19430&p=83757&viewfull=1#post83757).

**The Code**

```
<ext:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" Text="Download" runat="server">
        <DirectEvents>
            <Click OnEvent="lnkDownload_Click" Success="Ext.net.DirectMethods.Download({ isUpload : true });" IsUpload="true">
                <EventMask ShowMask="true" />
            </Click>
        </DirectEvents>
</ext:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Due to the event mask, the loading sign did not stop. So do I have to remove the showmask="true" or is there any other way to stop it?

Comment: Yes, but it turns out that we need to add IsUpload = "true" to the click event. thanks.

Comment: @FREAKYHUNTER aha will modify the answer then